# I'm wearing a hat, but the Winter Bash dropdown indicates that I have not earned any hats yet

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

I've earned quite a few hats, but the Winter Bash dropdown displays the *"You have not earned any hat yet"* message.

Snapshot:

[image: You have not earned any hat yet]

Comment: Maybe that dropdown is time travelling backwards? When you didn't have hats yet?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Almost at the sametime when I posted the question. I registered 2 pottential [bug] and [feature-request]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this issue any more.

Seems the development team was quick enough to plugin the fix as soon as the issue was raised. Kudos to the lightening fast response.